# How could I get consecutive pairs in a column with duplication?

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm struggling to find a way to get consecutive pairs in a column of a table but failed so far. To explain more specifically, let me give an example.

Let's say I have a table (t1) with 1 column (col1) of char as follows:

```
col1
------
a
a
a
c
e
a
g
i
```

What I want to get is consecutive pairs like
`(a,a) (a,a) (a,c) (c,e) (e,a) (a g) (g,i)`.
For example, building a new table(t2) which has a column(col2) of string as follows:

```
col2
------
a,a
a,a
a,c
c,e
e,a
a,g
g,i
```

(if I can exclude the pairs of same value (e.g. (a,a)), it would be better)

Please assume that there is no analytic function like lag() and unable to use pl/sql.
I have to solve this problem with basic sql statements.

I have a quite simple sql query to solve this kind of problem as follow:

```
select t1.col as col1, min(t2.col) as col2
from table1 t1 inner join table1 t2 on t2.col > t1.col
group by t1.col
order by t1.col
```

But this query is working when we assume there is no duplication.

Please help. Any comment or idea would be very thankful.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: In fact, I am not using well-known RDBMS. My team implements a system which support sql-like queries, almost every basic sql queries. Do you have any idea to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The order rows are returned isn't deterministic in the absence of an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. That means *consecutive* is meaningless in your first table, and that the order you get today is liable to be different from the order you get next week.

Comment: I agree. It's my fault. I overly simplified my problem. I assumed that my first table(t1) is a result from a query using "order by" clause. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER to achieve this:

```
SELECT a.col,b.col
FROM    (SELECT col,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 'Row_Rank'
         FROM Table1
         )a
LEFT JOIN    (SELECT col,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 'Row_Rank'
         FROM Table1
        )b
ON a.Row_Rank = b.Row_Rank - 1
```

Ideally you'd have something that you could segment this by, as it's nice to ensure ordering, but the above works.  The ROW_NUMBER just creates a number for each row, which you can use to self-join with an offset of 1 row.

EDIT:  Changed to LEFT JOIN, depending on what you want to return for the last record you can use LEFT or INNER, and you could wrap the selected columns in ISNULL if you wanted to return a specific value to be paired with the last value that has no next row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt comment! Your answer definitely works!! Can I ask you one more question? Is there other solution that I can achieve same result without using ROW_NUMBER() function? Frankly speaking, I am using our own system which support sql-like queries. But it support only basic sql functions, not analytic functions like ROW_NUMBER. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Any auto-incrementing value would work in place of ROW_NUMBER.  Not sure what's available to you.

Comment: Yes. I totally agree!! Unfortunately, now we don't support adding an attribute that has auto-incrementing values. Therefore, I think I need different kind of approach which don't use the unique ids for each tuple. As I mentioned in the original content, one possible approach would be using inner join and min() function. But it has 'duplication' problem. Anyway, Thank you so much!! Please let me know if you have any idea :)

Comment: You could make your sub-quries into temp tables with an IDENTITY field, not terribly elegant, or use a quirky update approach.